# Are there any applications written in the Io programming language? (Or, distributing Io applications.)

Tags: software-distribution, iolanguage

I've recently become interested in prototype-based OOP, and I've been playing with Io and Ioke. Distributing an application with Ioke is simple. It's on the JVM. Need I say more? However, I'm absolutely stumped as to how one would distribute an Io application, especially on Windows. It's not like you can have end-users compile Io to run your application.

I was actually shocked the Io has gone for 8 years without forming some sort of standards for things like distribution. Ruby has gems, Java has jars, and so on.

The worse thing about it is, I can't find a single application written in Io to maybe steal ideas on distribution from. Maybe I suck at google searching (Io is a horrible search name, by the way ;P).

Is there any sort of canonical way to distribute Io applications? Are there even any Io applications in existence, or am I just missing the point?

I'm not sure if this should be community wiki or not. If you think it should, comment and let me know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As for standards for *packaging* / *distribution* there is the `Addons`.  It seems to be mainly geared for added C libraries to `Io` but should work with pure `Io` code as well.

The `Addons` documentation is a little sparse.  There is a [Writing Addons](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Io_Programming/Writing_Addons) wiki page which may help. But best bet is to just delve into `Addons` which hopefully is included with your `Io` install.   Source for these can be found on Github in [addons](http://github.com/stevedekorte/io/tree/master/addons/) under the main [Io project](http://github.com/stevedekorte/io).

Just to beef up bit about [`Io`](http://www.iolanguage.com) programs/projects is on [`Github`](http://github.com), here are some Github links:

- [Overview of Io projects on Github](http://github.com/languages/Io)
- [Complete list of Io projects on Github (includes forks)](http://github.com/languages/Io/created)

There are a few fledgling packaging projects listed there which, in time, one of which may gain traction and perhaps universal adoption?:

- [boid](http://github.com/jdp/boid)
- [iopackage](http://github.com/oleganza/iopackage)
- [eerie](http://github.com/josip/eerie)

**Update**: There is a recent(ish) discussion on the [Io mailing list](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/iolanguage/) about [packaging](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/iolanguage/message/11897).  No outcome as yet.

/I3az/

Answer (score 3):

The Io website contains a list of libraries and applications

http://iolanguage.org/packages.html

Additionally, there may be projects (mainly on GitHub) using Io which are not
listed there.

Also the Io website and the blog are written in Io.